# How can I calculate the trotter error for a given Hamiltonian?

Tags: simulations, quantum-computer, time-evolution

I have the following Hamiltonian

$$
H = \sum_i \epsilon_i\sigma^z_i +  \sum_{i \neq j} J_{ij}(\sigma^x_i \sigma^x_j + \sigma^y_i \sigma^y_j)
$$

with the Pauli matrices $\sigma^x$, $\sigma^y$ and $\sigma^z$. The sum in the above Hamiltonian is over lattice sites for example. The onsite energies are $\epsilon_i$ and the coupling between the sites is $J_{ij}$

When simulation the Hamiltonian $H$ on a quantum computer, one usually does a trotterization. The trotterization comes with an error if the terms in in $H$ do not commute.

Can someone explain me how to calculate the trotter error (first order) explicitely? It will depend on $\epsilon_i$ and $J_{ij}$ (I assume) but how does the equation look like?

Thanks you for your comments in advance!